# Angular bind 2 select dropdowns to object and store only the selected value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my Angular component I'm using 2 html select dropdowns. The model dropdown shows the models of the selected brand above. Currently the problem is that I want to store both as string but in code I get the whole object from brand dropdown. If I change `ngValue` of brand into `[ngValue]="brand.name"`, the bind with the model select will not work anymore. Currently the selected car brand is on submit of my form stored as the brand object and the car model stored as a string.

How can I select a model of the selected brand and also store the brand as string?

This is my code

```
<form *ngIf="car" #carEditForm="ngForm" name="form" (ngSubmit)="carEditForm.form.valid 
&& onSubmit()">
    <label for="brand">Car brand</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="car.brand" name="brand" required>
        <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" [ngValue]="brand">{{ brand.name }}</option>
    </select>
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <select *ngIf="car.brand" [(ngModel)]="car.model" class="form-control" name="model" 
     required>
        <option *ngFor="let model of car.brand.models" value="{{ model }}">
            {{ model }} 
        </option>
    </select>
    ...
</form>
```

And the classes:

```
export class Car {
  key: string
  brand: string
  model: string
}

export class Brand {
  key: string
  name: string
  models: []
}
```

Edit: Solution in comments

Comment: share your code how you are population the models and brands list/object. 
Secondly if you are receiving an Object why don't you get the required attribute from it in typescript when saving?

Comment: If you're setting `car.brand` to a brand in brands, then `car.brand` shouldn't be a `string`, it should be a `Brand` object/class. If you set it to `car.brand.name`, then your second select can't work on any properties of that string, so you'd need another method of getting the list of models for that brand to display in the 2nd select.

Comment: Or try something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-qcwmco?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help, your code example helped me a lot solving my problem @Sean!